# Flask: request.view_args always returns an empty dicitonary

Tags: flask, jinja2

I am trying to paginate my products catalog using `paginate()` function that comes with **Flask** .

Inside catalog i am using a search filter to sort products depends on the filter itself, in the **url** i have more than 5 to 10 arguments, these arguments are always changing and i want the paginate **path** to contain them .

Inside template i am doing this:

```
{% if pagination.has_next or pagination.has_prev %}
{{ 
    macros.pagination_widget(
        pagination,
        request.endpoint,
        args=request.view_args
    )
}}
{% endif %}
```

The issue is, `request.view_args` always returns an empty dictionary , in fact the arguments are in **url** .

If i tried to hardcode all the arguments by using just some logic like `{% if %}` and `{% else %}` which i don't want to, the pagination works just fine .

Comment: Does your view define those arguments?

Comment: @Mekicha no it doesn't , do i have ? i mean i can get arguments from `request.args` for example without defining them inside my view !

Comment: `request.args ` accesses the parsed URL parameters (the part in the URL after the question mark). `view_args `is A dict of view arguments that matched the request, for instance if  you have a view function that takes a user_id variable like this: `def get_user(user_id)`.

Comment: Oh i see, so `request.view_args` working just if you are passing some arguments to your view .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, by using `request.query_string` and creating a **macro** helper everything now is working just fine.

Here is the solution:

**_macros_pagination.html**

```
{% macro pagination_widget(pagination, endpoint, extra='') %}
    <ul class="uk-pagination uk-flex-center" uk-margin="">
        <li{% if not pagination.has_prev %} class="disabled"{% endif %}>
            <a href="{% if pagination.has_prev %}{{ url_for(endpoint, page=pagination.prev_num, **kwargs) }}&{{extra}}{% else %}#{% endif %}">
                <span uk-pagination-previous=""></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        {% for p in pagination.iter_pages() %}
            {% if p %}
                {% if p == pagination.page %}
                <li class="uk-active">
                    <a href="{{ url_for(endpoint, page = p, **kwargs) }}&{{extra}}">{{ p }}</a>
                </li>
                {% else %}
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ url_for(endpoint, page = p, **kwargs) }}&{{extra}}">{{ p }}</a>
                </li>
                {% endif %}
            {% else %}
            <li class="uk-disabled"><span>...</span></li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        <li{% if not pagination.has_next %} class="disabled"{% endif %}>
            <a href="{% if pagination.has_next %}{{ url_for(endpoint, page=pagination.next_num, **kwargs) }}&{{extra}}{% else %}#{% endif %}">
                <span uk-pagination-next=""></span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
{% endmacro %}
```

**template.html**

```
{% import "_macros_pagination.html" as macros %}

{% if pagination.has_next or pagination.has_prev %}
    {{ 
        macros.pagination_widget(
            pagination,
            request.endpoint,
            extra=request.query_string
        )
    }}
{% endif %}
```